# Protecting database data

Tags: mysql, database

Currently I'm using a MySQL database. Let's say that I have some data regarding last month. When the data has been verified I want to "lock" it, so when my boss asks me if the data is correct, I can answer yes, because I'm certain that the data couldn't have been altered in the mean time.

Is there a way to "lock" data rows or cells from being modified? How could I do that?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by lock.
If you lock your data how will your will be able to update the tables.

Based on your problem whatever i have understood, you can create a backup DB and put your verified data there and don't provide modify access to someone other than you to keep that data safe.

Comment: make an offline backup of the relevant data and secure it so that no-one (except an authorised administrator, obviously) can modify it. Hard to see how else you could reasonably guarantee it. Or perhaps you need a reporting data warehouse solution which provides snapshots of historical data which do not get modified regardless of what happens to the "live" database. Or implement some business rules in the application(s) using the database so that records beyond a certain date cannot be updated. But that obviously requires a lot more testing and maintenance.

Comment: InnoDB's read locks might help you out here i geuss. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

Mysql innoDB lock may works,  but is not permanent I think (related to transactions). Check yourself [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-record-locks)

I would suggest you add an extra column in your table, name it for eg. `validated` with default value `0`. Then when every rows are validated, you change `validated` value to `1`. If so, you can add a trigger to check update on this current table.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateRestrictionOnMyTable
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.validated > 0  THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot update validated rows';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```